# GeoGraphics : path within a country

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, geography

I am using `GeoGraphics` to visualize electricity distribution networks in certain countries. I have susbtation location data, as well as network incidence matrices (i.e. which substations are connected to each other). From this I simply create a list of transmission lines by creating pairs of substations and putting it into a `Line` wrapper.

```
Line[{GeoPosition[{21.0112, 105.808, 0}],GeoPosition[{13.9719, 108.015, 0}]}]
```

In some cases though, a straight line will go through another country, or even worse over the ocean. For example, here in Vietnam.

```
GeoGraphics[{Line[{GeoPosition[{21.0112, 105.808, 0}], GeoPosition[{13.9719, 108.015, 0}]}], Polygon[Entity["Country", "Vietnam"]]}]
```

[image]

So my question is : **How can I make a "straight" or shortest path that stays within a country?** (or at least doesn't go over oceans!)

I have tried adapting [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PathsInsideAPolygon/) to my case but can't get it to work.

Comment: Not the fastest path but quite short solution: `GeoGraphics@
 TravelDirections[{GeoPosition[{21.0112, 105.808}], 
    GeoPosition[{13.9719, 108.015}]}]["TravelPath"]`

Comment: @Kuba I get an error when evaluating this.
An unknown box name (TravelDirections[{GeoPosition[{21.0112, 105.808}], GeoPosition[{13.9719, 108.015}]}]) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

Comment: It's new in 10.3.

Comment: aha. I haven't made the jump from 10.2 yet. I will try it on another PC which does have 10.3

Comment: don't worry it's not a solution you are after, it doesn't give the shortest path: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TravelDirections.html

Comment: I see. Actually, I could reword my question since I am not necessarly looking for the shortest path. I could do with one that simply has straight segments while staying within the country. In that sense, I guess a possible solution could go about finding a sort of middle line between the coast and border and following that until reaching the vicinity of the endpoint. But that wouldn't provide a general solution that can be applied to any other country.

Comment: One relatively simple way would be: generate a square grid of points within the `RegionBounds` of Vietnam and select those that are in Vietnam itself.  Construct the `NearestNeighborGraph`, connecting every point to every other that is closer than a given radius.  Use `FindShortestPath` to find a path in this graph.  Convert back to coordinates and plot on the map.  All the conversions between graph vertices, plot coordinates and geographical coordinates will take some effort but it should work ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a solution I can think of. Idea is to take the `FullPolygon` of a given country and then triangulate the region. Once that is done take the underlying `Graph` and do a `FindShortestPath`. Result will not be too bad.

```
fullPoly = CountryData["Vietnam", "FullPolygon"];
pts = Flatten[fullPoly[[1, 1]], 1];
line = Polygon[Range[##]] & @@@ Partition[{1}~Join~
 Most[Riffle[Accumulate[Length /@ #], 
     1 + Accumulate[Length /@ #]] &@fullPoly[[1, 1]]], 2];
country = Quiet@DiscretizeRegion[MeshRegion[pts, line], MaxCellMeasure -> .004]
```

Let's construct the `Graph` and find the shortest path.

```
graph = Graph[MeshCoordinates[country], 
MeshCells[country, 1] /. Line[{start_, end_}] -> {start, end}, 
VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[country], 
GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"];
fun = Nearest[GeoPosition[{MeshCoordinates[country]}]];
(* the start and end point you gave *)
{st, en} = Flatten[fun /@ 
{GeoPosition[{21.0112, 105.808, 0}],GeoPosition[{13.9719, 108.015, 0}]}
] /.GeoPosition[{a_, b_}] :> {a, b};
(* the shortest path *)
path = FindShortestPath[graph, st, en];
HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[path],GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Now plotting the path on the map with little style is easy with `GeoGraphics`.

```
GeoGraphics[{Dashed, Thick, Red, Arrow@GeoPath[path, "Geodesic"], 
Orange, PointSize[0.025], Point@GeoPosition[st], Blue,PointSize[0.025],
Point@GeoPosition[en],Directive[Opacity@.05, Pink], 
Polygon[Entity["Country", "Vietnam"]]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The above method should work for most countries. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Two questions: Is it me or do the paths not match perfectly? (In the GeoGraphis one, the path seems to follow the coastline for a bit, while in the graph it does not) Also, can I increase the resolution in polygons, or maybe "straighten" the line? cheers.

Comment: The graph image was done with less mesh resolution (`MaxCellMeasure -> .04`) as it looks better and we can see the edges better. The `GeoGraphics` image is result of using `MaxCellMeasure -> .004` which is probably a good setting for a fine mesh resolution. You are of course free to increase the resolution. Both the path will be same for a fixed `MaxCellMeasure ` setting.

Comment: @Emy To straighten the segments of the line you'd be likely to reduce the resolution in polygons; to make the line shorter you'd increase the resolution.

Comment: @tricasse Thanks as well. That's good to know. Although I assume that with less resolution the line will be somewhat more erratic going left and right. I'll play around with this to see what better suits me.